# CakePHP - How to pass a $variable to the find function in a controller

Tags: cakephp

All,

I wanted to know how I could pass a $variable from view, for example, current article id ( $article['Article']['id'] ) to the find('all') call in a function in articles_controller.php.

```
function getRelated($id = null){
$relatedarticles = $this->Article->find(
                    'all',
                    array(
                         'fields' => array(
                        'Article.title'
                        ),
                         'limit' => 4,
                         'order' => 'Article.id ASC',
                         'recursive' => 1,
                         'conditions' => array(
                        'Article.category_id =' => $id
                         )
                         )
                    );

if (!empty($this->params['requested'])) {
    return $relatedarticles;
} else {
    $this->set(compact('relatedarticles'));
}
}
```

And then from the view, I would call something like this. I cant seem to get this to work... what is the best way to do this?

```
<div id="articles_view_related">
Related News
<?php 
    $currentid = $articles['Article']['id'];
    $relatedarticles = $this->requestAction('/articles/getRelated/id:$currentid');
    //debug($relatedarticles);
?>
<ul>
    <?php
        foreach($relatedarticles as $relatedarticle){
    ?>
    <li>
        <?php
            echo $relatedarticle['Article']['title'];
        ?>
    </li>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</ul>

</div>
```

thank you for all your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm struggling to work out why you are doing this task in this way, but here is your answer nonetheless:

```
$relatedarticles = $this->requestAction('/articles/getRelated/'.$currentid);
```

You don't need `id:$currendId`, because of the parameter in your action, anything after /controller/action/ in a URL will be declared as `$id` in `getRelated($id = null);` eg: `/articles/getRelated/23` and `$id` will equal 23.

---

What you *should* be doing, is declaring the `getRelated()` method in your **model,** and then using the controller action to get the contents, and pass it to the view.
eg:

```
$relatedArticles = $this->Article->getRelated($article['Article']['id']);
$this->set(compact('relatedArticles));
```

For data manipulation you want to repeat, stick it in your models :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick reply. I am new to CakePHP and MVC altogether, and very often I get stuck trying to figure out what goes where. If I am implying correctly, I should create a getRelated($id = null) function in my articles model just like I have it above, but without the if statement. Then use your suggested code in my controller (Do I create the same function here?). In my view, I should then remove the requestAction call. I appreciate your help on this...

Comment: Yeah I think you've grasped it, if you want to include related articles in any of your other actions (which I think is your overall goal), just put call to `$this->Article->getRelated()` inside your other action.

Comment: Awesome... You are correct. I would like to use getRelated in my other actions as well. Thanks for the lesson... I will try what you have suggested and post back later.